How to change height and depht for superscript and subscript outside math mode?
To display in a decent way both superscript and subscript after some text I'm using these commands
\rlap{\textsuperscript{}}\textsubscript{}

and it works.
I'm looking for a way to increase the vertical space between the superscript and the subscript.


You can define the combination more properly. With your code TeX is not aware that there are both a subscript and a superscript.
You also don't need to guess what's the shorter part.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\textsubsuper}{mm}{%
  \@textsubsuper{\selectfont #1}{\selectfont #2}%
}
\newcommand{\@textsubsuper}[2]{%
 {\m@th\ensuremath{%
   _{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\sf@size #1}}%
   ^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\sf@size #2}}%
 }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textbf{Friends\textsubsuper{\itshape Concentration}{\itshape Ritual}}

\end{document}



I can only partially understand what is happening in command definition :


What does the "mm" mean in \textsubsuper}{mm} ?


Why there is a "\sf@size" twice in line of the \mbox ?


Making tex aware of both subscript and superscript is done by using the math mode? Is it the only method, isn't it?



@Paul \fontsize takes two arguments: the font size proper and the baseline skip; since we're not making paragraphs, 0 as the second argument would do as well. I just merged the definitions of \textsubscript and \textsuperscript, which indeed use math mode. The mm part means that the command to be defined takes to mandatory arguments.

please have a bit more patience. I still don't understand why "\sf@size"  was needed twice in these lines :
_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\sf@size #1}}%
^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\sf@size #2}}%

@Paul As I said, \fontsize wants two arguments. In this particular case, the second one can be any dimension, because it’s about the baseline skip. Who wrote the command decided for \sf@size instead of 0.

When we are using math mode for placing these subscripts, superscripts, then the vertical spacing between them look OK. For example, using \mathbox from OpTeX:
\def\spsb#1#2{$^{\mathbox{\it #1}}_{\mathbox{\it #2}}$}

{\bf Friends}\spsb{Ritual}{Concentration}

\bye



Using the altsubsup package since 2022.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{altsubsup}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\bm{Friends}_{\bm{Concentration}}^{\bm{Ritual}}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}


